# Context menu not working after upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from MOSS 2007, when we try the new interface (preview mode), some context menus are not working - if a user clicks e. g. view properties, edit properties, approve/reject... etc, nothing happens. When the user clicks the "Edit item" icon, it works fine.

It happens only sometimes and to some users. There are some customizations, but nothing serious - for example an inserted CEWP above the list - but only sometimes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a JavaScript problem that might caused by the CEWP (assuming they contains JavaScript)
You could try deleting the CEWP, if it works after that then you will need to review the code in the webpart.
if its not then you might have a custom theme or other customization that is causing problems

Comment: Hello Renzo,
yes, it seemed to me that the JS in a CEWP might be the cause. However, it doesnt work also in pages that do NOT have a CEWP, and, whats more, only to some users (e. g. one user with ReadWriteEdit permissions has a non-working context menu). We do not have any custom themes and I dont know about any customizations that may cause this behavior - if any, they are, in general, applied throughout the whole portal. Are there any ways to a sort of debug the context menu?

Comment: hi, you can try to debug the JavaScript on the page using the developer tools from IE (go to tools > Developer tools) then got to the script tab and click the start debugging button, reload the page and watch the console for errors

Comment: Well, tried this. The result is: trying to go to dispform/editform - nothing at all - just nothing happens, trying "Alert me" - works, trying Manage permissions - works, but with an error (see http://img243.imageshack.us/img243/1493/jsdebug.jpg). More confusing than in the beginning :).
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it was a custom JavaScript in the site.